# Hibernates & postgresql persistence ids won't persist automatically ( id must be assi

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I get the following error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.xx.xx.xx.S3ObjectsEntity
```

I already tried this without any effect:

- [ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save():](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997494/ids-for-this-class-must-be-manually-assigned-before-calling-save)
- [Hibernate: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142071/hibernate-ids-for-this-class-must-be-manually-assigned-before-calling-save)
- [ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save() when entities have relation between their primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697561/ids-for-this-class-must-be-manually-assigned-before-calling-save-when-entities)
- [ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463638/ids-for-this-class-must-be-manually-assigned-before-calling-save)

None of the above will work and I get the same error message.

This is my Entity.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "s3objects", schema = "public", catalog = "CustomerReportBDD")
public class S3ObjectsEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "s3objects_id",unique=true, nullable = false)
private Long s3Objects_Id;
@Basic
@Column(name = "etag", nullable = true, length = 100)
private String etag;
@Basic
@Column(name = "bucketname", nullable = true, length = 100)
private String bucketname;
@Basic
@Column(name = "objectkey", nullable = true, length = 100)
private String objectkey;
@Basic
@Column(name = "lastmodified", nullable = true, length = 100)
private String lastmodified;
@Basic
@Column(name = "storageclass", nullable = true, length = 100)
private String storageclass;
@Basic
@Column(name = "owner_id", nullable = true)
private Integer owner_id;
```

And the sql script that I used to create the table :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS s3objects CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE s3objects (
s3objects_id   SERIAL,
etag          varchar(100),
bucketname    varchar(100),
objectkey     varchar(100),
lastmodified  varchar(100),
storageclass  varchar(100),
owner_id      varchar(100) ,
CONSTRAINT s3objectsKey PRIMARY KEY(s3objects_id)
);
```

The owner id is nullable in the base.

I works perfectly, when I manually add all fields in the base (with s3object_id & owner_id at null)

I tried to do that on the entity:

```
@GeneratedValue ( strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
```

And that:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="s3ObjectSequence", sequenceName = "s3objects_s3objects_id_seq",allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue ( strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "s3ObjectSequence")
```

s3objects_s3objects_id_seq is a sequence present in the base after the creation of the table in the database.

Edit 1:

added the option

```
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="1000" />
  <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
</properties>
```

In my `persist.xml`

The tables are created from entities but I always get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Each database driver implements Id generation strategy in a different way. Which driver are you using? JPA/hibernate version?

Try to put this hibernate option "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create" in a development environment. It will create your table and the sequence automatically. Copy the generated schema in your script.

If you put @Id, you do not need to write "unique=true, nullable = false" on the column.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "s3objects_id")
private Long s3Objects_Id;
```

Comment: where can I see that ? ( what file ) ? 
And thanks for the precision on @id

Comment: Are you using a persistence.xml file?  Spring boot?  Spring? Where is defined the persistence provider, datasource, entity manager..?

Comment: Haaa i ot a datasource.xml :
 <bean name='hibernateJPAOnPostgre' class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
  <property name="showSql" value="true" />
  <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect" />
  <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
 </bean>
And i'm using Spring ( i'm beginner on that fwk )

I got a : 
-persistenceunit.xml
-persist.xml 

In the project

Comment: Ok finally found what you meant in your message.
I'm editing the question to add your hibernate option ( not working )

Comment: @Slater Which postgres driver library are you using? Hibernate version? Do u have ManyToOne mappings?

Comment: No many to one mapping. Only this Entity actually no link done on this table ( but it will in near future ) 
For the postgresql : <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect" /> I guess you mean that
And for hibernates : hibernate version 5.0.6.Final

Comment: Driver jdbc : 9.4.1201 ( jdbc4)

Comment: The code looks correct and should work. @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) should do the work... If you want to use hibernate and Spring and you are starting a new project, I recommend you to use Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA.  You have an example project https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/